# What is the use of 'ENABLE' and then 'DISABLE'?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

At line 3 & 4 of the ALTER TABLE?

```
ALTER TABLE  "EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_DEPT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPARTMENT_ID")
        REFERENCES  "DEPARTMENTS" ("DEPARTMENT_ID") ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  "EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("JOB_ID")
        REFERENCES  "JOBS" ("JOB_ID") ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  "EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_MANAGER_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("MANAGER_ID")
        REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  "DEPARTMENTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "DEPT_MGR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("MANAGER_ID")
        REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") DISABLE;
CREATE INDEX  "EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("DEPARTMENT_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "EMP_JOB_IX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("JOB_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "EMP_MANAGER_IX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("MANAGER_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "EMP_NAME_IX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME");
```

These are the references tables.

```
CREATE TABLE  "DEPARTMENTS"
   ("DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
    "DEPARTMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT "DEPT_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
    "LOCATION_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
     CONSTRAINT "DEPT_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPARTMENT_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );

CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEES"
   ("EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20),
    "HIRE_DATE" DATE CONSTRAINT "EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "SALARY" NUMBER(8,2),
    "COMMISSION_PCT" NUMBER(2,2),
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
    "DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
        "BONUS" VARCHAR2(5),
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_SALARY_MIN" CHECK (salary > 0) ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_UK" UNIQUE ("EMAIL")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
  );
```

Attached also the whole script, if unclear what it is about.

```
CREATE TABLE  "REGIONS"
   ("REGION_ID" NUMBER CONSTRAINT "REGION_ID_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "REGION_NAME" VARCHAR2(25),
    CONSTRAINT "REG_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("REGION_ID")
    USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );
   
CREATE TABLE  "COUNTRIES"
   ("COUNTRY_ID" CHAR(2) CONSTRAINT "COUNTRY_ID_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "COUNTRY_NAME" VARCHAR2(40),
    "REGION_ID" NUMBER,
     CONSTRAINT "COUNTRY_C_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COUNTRY_ID") ENABLE
   );


ALTER TABLE  "COUNTRIES" ADD CONSTRAINT "COUNTR_REG_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("REGION_ID")
        REFERENCES  "REGIONS" ("REGION_ID") ENABLE;
   
CREATE TABLE  "LOCATIONS"
   ("LOCATION_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
    "STREET_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(40),
    "POSTAL_CODE" VARCHAR2(12),
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT "LOC_CITY_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "STATE_PROVINCE" VARCHAR2(25),
    "COUNTRY_ID" CHAR(2),
    CONSTRAINT "LOC_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LOCATION_ID")
    USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );
   
ALTER TABLE  "LOCATIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "LOC_C_ID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("COUNTRY_ID")
        REFERENCES  "COUNTRIES" ("COUNTRY_ID") ENABLE;
CREATE INDEX  "LOC_CITY_IX" ON  "LOCATIONS" ("CITY");
CREATE INDEX  "LOC_COUNTRY_IX" ON  "LOCATIONS" ("COUNTRY_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "LOC_STATE_PROVINCE_IX" ON  "LOCATIONS" ("STATE_PROVINCE");


CREATE TABLE  "DEPARTMENTS"
   ("DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
    "DEPARTMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT "DEPT_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
    "LOCATION_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
     CONSTRAINT "DEPT_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPARTMENT_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );
 
ALTER TABLE  "DEPARTMENTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "DEPT_LOC_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("LOCATION_ID")
        REFERENCES  "LOCATIONS" ("LOCATION_ID") ENABLE;


CREATE INDEX  "DEPT_LOCATION_IX" ON  "DEPARTMENTS" ("LOCATION_ID");
        
CREATE TABLE  "JOBS"
   ("JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10),
    "JOB_TITLE" VARCHAR2(35) CONSTRAINT "JOB_TITLE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "MIN_SALARY" NUMBER(6,0),
    "MAX_SALARY" NUMBER(6,0),
     CONSTRAINT "JOB_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("JOB_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );
        
CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEES"
   ("EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20),
    "HIRE_DATE" DATE CONSTRAINT "EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "SALARY" NUMBER(8,2),
    "COMMISSION_PCT" NUMBER(2,2),
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
    "DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
        "BONUS" VARCHAR2(5),
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_SALARY_MIN" CHECK (salary > 0) ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_UK" UNIQUE ("EMAIL")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
  );
  
ALTER TABLE  "EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_DEPT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPARTMENT_ID")
        REFERENCES  "DEPARTMENTS" ("DEPARTMENT_ID") ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  "EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("JOB_ID")
        REFERENCES  "JOBS" ("JOB_ID") ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  "EMPLOYEES" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_MANAGER_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("MANAGER_ID")
        REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE  "DEPARTMENTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "DEPT_MGR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("MANAGER_ID")
        REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") DISABLE;
CREATE INDEX  "EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("DEPARTMENT_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "EMP_JOB_IX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("JOB_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "EMP_MANAGER_IX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("MANAGER_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "EMP_NAME_IX" ON  "EMPLOYEES" ("LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME");


CREATE TABLE  "JOB_GRADES"
   ("GRADE_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(3),
    "LOWEST_SAL" NUMBER,
    "HIGHEST_SAL" NUMBER
   );


CREATE TABLE  "JOB_HISTORY"
   ("EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0) CONSTRAINT "JHIST_EMPLOYEE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "START_DATE" DATE CONSTRAINT "JHIST_START_DATE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "END_DATE" DATE CONSTRAINT "JHIST_END_DATE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT "JHIST_JOB_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
     CONSTRAINT "JHIST_DATE_INTERVAL" CHECK (end_date > start_date) ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "JHIST_EMP_ID_ST_DATE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID", "START_DATE")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   );


ALTER TABLE  "JOB_HISTORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "JHIST_DEPT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPARTMENT_ID")
        REFERENCES  "DEPARTMENTS" ("DEPARTMENT_ID") ENABLE;
-- the folowing FK constraint is disabled as table contains historical data for employees that are not in the current employees table
ALTER TABLE  "JOB_HISTORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "JHIST_EMP_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
          REFERENCES  "EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") DISABLE;
ALTER TABLE  "JOB_HISTORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "JHIST_JOB_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("JOB_ID")
          REFERENCES  "JOBS" ("JOB_ID") ENABLE;
CREATE INDEX  "JHIST_DEPARTMENT_IX" ON  "JOB_HISTORY" ("DEPARTMENT_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "JHIST_EMPLOYEE_IX" ON  "JOB_HISTORY" ("EMPLOYEE_ID");
CREATE INDEX  "JHIST_JOB_IX" ON  "JOB_HISTORY" ("JOB_ID");


--populate regions table
INSERT INTO regions (region_id, region_name)
Values(1,'Europe');
INSERT INTO regions (region_id, region_name)
Values(2,'Americas');
INSERT INTO regions (region_id, region_name)
Values(3,'Asia');
INSERT INTO regions (region_id, region_name)
Values(4,'Middle East and Africa');


--populate countries table
INSERT INTO countries (country_id, country_name, region_id)
Values('CA','Canada',2);
INSERT INTO countries (country_id, country_name, region_id)
Values('DE','Germany',1);
INSERT INTO countries (country_id, country_name, region_id)
Values('UK','United Kingdom',1);
INSERT INTO countries (country_id, country_name, region_id)
Values('US','United States of America',2);


--populate locations table
INSERT INTO locations (location_id, street_address, postal_code, city, state_province, country_id)
Values(1800,'460 Bloor St. W.','ON M5S 1X8','Toronto','Ontario','CA');
INSERT INTO locations (location_id, street_address, postal_code, city, state_province, country_id)
Values(2500,'Magdalen Centre, The Oxford Science Park','OX9 9ZB','Oxford','Oxford','UK');
INSERT INTO locations (location_id, street_address, postal_code, city, state_province, country_id)
Values(1400,'2014 Jabberwocky Rd','26192','Southlake','Texas','US');
INSERT INTO locations (location_id, street_address, postal_code, city, state_province, country_id)
Values(1500,'2011 Interiors Blvd','99236','South San Francisco','California','US');
INSERT INTO locations (location_id, street_address, postal_code, city, state_province, country_id)
Values(1700,'2004 Charade Rd','98199','Seattle','Washington','US');


--populate departments table
INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
Values(10,'Administration',200,1700);
INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
Values(20,'Marketing',201,1800);
INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
Values(50,'Shipping',124,1500);
INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
Values(60,'IT',103,1400);
INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
Values(80,'Sales',149,2500);
INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
Values(90,'Executive',100,1700);
INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
Values(110,'Accounting',205,1700);
INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id)
Values(190,'Contracting',null,1700);


--populate jobs table
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('AD_PRES','President',20000,40000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('AD_VP','Administration Vice President',15000,30000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('AD_ASST','Administration Assistant',3000,6000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('AC_MGR','Accounting Manager',8200,16000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('AC_ACCOUNT','Public Accountant',4200,9000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('SA_MAN','Sales Manager',10000,20000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('SA_REP','Sales Representative',6000,12000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('ST_MAN','Stock Manager',5500,8500);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('ST_CLERK','Stock Clerk',2000,5000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('IT_PROG','Programmer',4000,10000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('MK_MAN','Marketing Manager',9000,15000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary)
Values('MK_REP','Marketing Representative',4000,9000);


--populate employees table
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(100,'Steven','King','SKING','515.123.4567',TO_DATE('1987-06-17','yyyy-mm-dd'),'AD_PRES',24000,null,null,90);
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(101,'Neena','Kochhar','NKOCHHAR','515.123.4568',TO_DATE('1989-09-21','yyyy-mm-dd'),'AD_VP',17000,null,100,90 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(102,'Lex','De Haan','LDEHAAN','515.123.4569',TO_DATE('1993-01-13','yyyy-mm-dd'),'AD_VP',17000,null,100,90 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(200,'Jennifer','Whalen','JWHALEN','515.123.4444',TO_DATE('1987-09-17','yyyy-mm-dd'),'AD_ASST',4400,null,101,10 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(205,'Shelley','Higgins','SHIGGINS','515.123.8080',TO_DATE('1994-06-07','yyyy-mm-dd'),'AC_MGR',12000,null,101,110 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(206,'William','Gietz','WGIETZ','515.123.8181',TO_DATE('1994-06-07','yyyy-mm-dd'),'AC_ACCOUNT',8300,null,205,110 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id, bonus)
VALUES(149,'Eleni','Zlotkey','EZLOTKEY','011.44.1344.429018',TO_DATE('2000-01-29','yyyy-mm-dd'),'SA_MAN',10500,.2,100,80, '1500' );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id, bonus)
VALUES(174,'Ellen','Abel','EABEL','011.44.1644.429267',TO_DATE('1996-05-11','yyyy-mm-dd'),'SA_REP',11000,.3,149,80,'1700' );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id, bonus)
VALUES(176,'Jonathon','Taylor','JTAYLOR','011.44.1644.429265',TO_DATE('1998-03-24','yyyy-mm-dd'),'SA_REP',8600,.2,149,80,'1250' );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(178,'Kimberely','Grant','KGRANT','011.44.1644.429263',TO_DATE('1999-05-24','yyyy-mm-dd'),'SA_REP',7000,.15,149,null );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(124,'Kevin','Mourgos','KMOURGOS','650.123.5234',TO_DATE('1999-11-16','yyyy-mm-dd'),'ST_MAN',5800,null,100,50);
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(141,'Trenna','Rajs','TRAJS','650.121.8009',TO_DATE('1995-10-17','yyyy-mm-dd'),'ST_CLERK',3500,null,124,50 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(142,'Curtis','Davies','CDAVIES','650.121.2994',TO_DATE('1997-01-29','yyyy-mm-dd'),'ST_CLERK',3100,null,124,50 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(143,'Randall','Matos','RMATOS','650.121.2874',TO_DATE('1998-03-15','yyyy-mm-dd'),'ST_CLERK',2600,null,124,50 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(144,'Peter','Vargas','PVARGAS','650.121.2004',TO_DATE('1998-07-09','yyyy-mm-dd'),'ST_CLERK',2500,null,124,50 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(103,'Alexander','Hunold','AHUNOLD','590.423.4567',TO_DATE('1990-01-03','yyyy-mm-dd'),'IT_PROG',9000,null,102,60 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(104,'Bruce','Ernst','BERNST','590.423.4568',TO_DATE('1991-05-21','yyyy-mm-dd'),'IT_PROG',6000,null,103,60 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(107,'Diana','Lorentz','DLORENTZ','590.423.5567',TO_DATE('1999-02-07','yyyy-mm-dd'),'IT_PROG',4200,null,103,60 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(201,'Michael','Hartstein','MHARTSTE','515.123.5555',TO_DATE('1996-02-17','yyyy-mm-dd'),'MK_MAN',13000,null,100,20 );
INSERT INTO employees(employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,commission_pct,manager_id,department_id)
VALUES(202,'Pat','Fay','PFAY','603.123.6666',TO_DATE('1997-08-17','yyyy-mm-dd'),'MK_REP',6000,null,201,20 );


--populate job_history table
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(200,TO_DATE('09-17-1987','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('06-17-1993','mm-dd-yyyy'),'AD_ASST',90 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(101,TO_DATE('10-28-1993','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('03-15-1997','mm-dd-yyyy'),'AC_MGR',110 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(200,TO_DATE('07-01-1994','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('12-31-1998','mm-dd-yyyy'),'AC_ACCOUNT',90 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(101,TO_DATE('09-21-1989','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('10-27-1993','mm-dd-yyyy'),'AC_ACCOUNT',110 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(176,TO_DATE('01-01-1999','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('12-31-1999','mm-dd-yyyy'),'SA_MAN',80 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(176,TO_DATE('03-24-1998','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('12-31-1998','mm-dd-yyyy'),'SA_REP',80 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(122,TO_DATE('01-01-1999','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('12-31-1999','mm-dd-yyyy'),'ST_CLERK',50 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(114,TO_DATE('03-24-1998','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('12-31-1999','mm-dd-yyyy'),'ST_CLERK',50 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(102,TO_DATE('01-13-1993','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('07-24-1998','mm-dd-yyyy'),'IT_PROG',60 );
INSERT INTO job_history(employee_id,start_date,end_date,job_id,department_id)
VALUES(201,TO_DATE('02-17-1996','mm-dd-yyyy'),TO_DATE('12-19-1999','mm-dd-yyyy'),'MK_REP',20 );


--populate job_grades table
INSERT INTO job_grades(grade_level,lowest_sal,highest_sal)
VALUES('A',1000,2999);
INSERT INTO job_grades(grade_level,lowest_sal,highest_sal)
VALUES('B',3000,5999);
INSERT INTO job_grades(grade_level,lowest_sal,highest_sal)
VALUES('C',6000,9999);
INSERT INTO job_grades(grade_level,lowest_sal,highest_sal)
VALUES('D',10000,14999);
INSERT INTO job_grades(grade_level,lowest_sal,highest_sal)
VALUES('E',15000,24999);
INSERT INTO job_grades(grade_level,lowest_sal,highest_sal)
VALUES('F',25000,40000);


ALTER TABLE  "DEPARTMENTS" ENABLE CONSTRAINT "DEPT_MGR_FK";


CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "EMP_DETAILS_VIEW" ("EMPLOYEE_ID", "JOB_ID", "MANAGER_ID", "DEPARTMENT_ID", "LOCATION_ID", "COUNTRY_ID", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "SALARY", "COMMISSION_PCT", "DEPARTMENT_NAME", "JOB_TITLE", "CITY", "STATE_PROVINCE", "COUNTRY_NAME", "REGION_NAME") 
        AS SELECT
                e.employee_id, e.job_id, e.manager_id, e.department_id,
                d.location_id,
                l.country_id,
                e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary, e.commission_pct,
                d.department_name,
                j.job_title,
                l.city, l.state_province,
                c.country_name,
                r.region_name
    FROM
        employees e,
        departments d,
        jobs j,
        locations l,
        countries c,
        regions r
    WHERE
        e.department_id = d.department_id
        AND d.location_id = l.location_id
        AND l.country_id = c.country_id
        AND c.region_id = r.region_id
        AND j.job_id = e.job_id
    WITH READ ONLY;
        
-- Drop sequences if they exist        
DROP SEQUENCE "DEPARTMENTS_SEQ";
DROP SEQUENCE "EMPLOYEES_SEQ";
DROP SEQUENCE "LOCATIONS_SEQ";


--Create sequence for departments PK                                
CREATE SEQUENCE "DEPARTMENTS_SEQ"  
        MINVALUE 1 
        MAXVALUE 9990 
        INCREMENT BY 10 
        START WITH 280 
        NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE;


--Create sequence for employees PK        
CREATE SEQUENCE "EMPLOYEES_SEQ"  
        MINVALUE 1 
        MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
        INCREMENT BY 1 
        START WITH 207 
        NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE;


--Create sequence for locations PK        
CREATE SEQUENCE "LOCATIONS_SEQ"  
        MINVALUE 1 
        MAXVALUE 9900 
        INCREMENT BY 100 
        START WITH 3300
```

Comment: Just to critique the script, use of double-quotes is poor practice because it can mask errors such as spaces in column names, as well as reducing readability, the `ENABLE` keyword is redundant when creating constraints as it is the default anyway, and `CHAR` is rarely a good idea as it merely increases the risk of bugs due to often unexpected blank padding semantics.

Comment: I didn't trace every detail, but I see that DEPT_MGR_FK is originally created disabled, then data is inserted into tables, then DEPT_MGR_FK is enabled.  I'd bet that on a closer examination, there are circular dependencies in the FK, so the only way to get the initial data load is to disable one of the FK until after all of the data is in place.

Answer (score 2):

They ([ENABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#i1010237) and [DISABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#i1002349) clauses) are both described in documentation.

Shortly:

- Specify `ENABLE` if you want the constraint to be applied to the data in the table.
- Specify `DISABLE` to disable the integrity constraint. Disabled integrity constraints appear in the data dictionary along with enabled constraints. If you do not specify this clause when creating a constraint, then Oracle automatically enables the constraint

Another interesting chapter is [Managing integrity constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/general005.htm).

---

Your question was:

> What is the use of 'ENABLE' and then 'DISABLE'?

If you look closer, it is not "ENABLE **and then** DISABLE" because DISABLE is applied to a different constraint (`DEPT_MGR_FK`) then the previous ones that script creates (e.g. `EMP_DEPT_FK`, `EMP_JOB_FK`, `EMP_MANAGER_FK`).

---

Why would you want to disable a constraint? One option is because of *circular reference* where two tables reference each other (via foreign key constraints). It means that - if those constraints were enabled - you wouldn't be able to insert data into any of them because every insert would fail as parent key value doesn't exist yet, so - disable constraints, load data, enable constraints - but you must be sure that data you inserted is valid, otherwise enabling the constraints will fail as well.

Comment: I see, I just know about this probably this is not covered from what I learnt, thanks for the clarification!